# Creating data frames from a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a function, `readnorm` which returns a list of related data from a file identified by an integer:

```
readnorm <- function(n) {
 a <- read.csv(paste("/tmp/diff-a-", n, ".txt", sep=""), 
               col.names=c("raw"), header=FALSE)
 a <- list(n=n, raw=a$raw, median=median(a$raw), iqr=IQR(a$raw))
 a$shifted <- a$raw - a$median
 a$scaled <- a$raw / a$iqr
 a$normed <- a$shifted / a$iqr
 a$necdf <- ecdf(a$normed)
 return(a)
}
```

I can build a list containing data from a set of files by using `lapply`:

```
> ns = c(5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20,25,30)
> data <- lapply(ns, readnorm)
> ls(data[[1]])
[1] "iqr"     "median"  "n"       "necdf"   "normed"  "raw"     "scaled" 
[8] "shifted"
```

Now, what I would like to do is construct from that a set of data frames, called `normed`, `scaled`, etc, which group the entries from the components in data (the names could be the values of `n` if integer names are allowed in R, so `normed$5` contains `data[[5]]$normed`, etc).

Does that make sense?  This way I can plot all the raw data by using the `raw` data frame, for example.  It's kind-of turning the data structure I have "inside out".

I am new to R so may be doing something very wrong.  In higher-level terms, I believe that the data in the different files are from similar distributions, shifted and scaled, and I want to explore that hypothesis.  The code above is my attempt to arrange things so that I can do so in a systematic manner.

So my main question is how to generate the data frames, but I am also interested in more general guidance about how to tackle this problem (how to manage the data - I know about tools like `qqplot` that will help with the analysis itself).

Comment: `sapply` is returning a matrix, if you use `lapply` it will return a list

Comment: ah, that explains the comma.  thanks - i'll update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comment that you will be happier using `lapply` rather than `sapply`. `sapply` is doing some simplifying that is actually complicatifying things for you.

More generally, if it were me, I'd do less computation in my function that reads the data, and save the processing for later, once the raw data have been placed in a single structure. For instance:

```
fun <- function(x){
    read.table(paste("~/Desktop/stackoverflowExamples/raw/raw",x,".txt",sep = ""),
                header = TRUE,sep = ",")
}

#Just read the raw data and place it all in a data frame
dat <- do.call(cbind,lapply(1:2,fun))
#One way to label the columns, if you want to keep track of what came from where
colnames(dat) <- paste("X",1:2,sep = "")

#Now you can shift and scale to your heart's content, much more compactly...
dat_shifted <- scale(dat,center = apply(dat,2,median),scale = FALSE)
dat_normed <- scale(dat,center = apply(dat,2,median),
                        scale = apply(dat,2,IQR))
```

I'm not sure what you plan on doing with the output of `ecdf`, so I'll just note that `ecdf()` returns a function (just in case you didn't realize that).

Finally, see `?make.names` for a description of what's allowed for names.

Comment: I agree with @joran about reading in the data and then worrying about processing later (although my answer does not do this!)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the "simplifying that is actually complicatifying things".

Comment: so `do.call` is what many languages call "apply", while `apply`, in its various forms, is what many languages call "map".  afaict.  thanks!

Comment: @andrewcooke I suppose, yes. If you're more comfortable with that terminology, you might find R's version of "functional programming" tools useful. See `?Map`.

Comment: oooh that seems a bit more familiar.  thanks!  :o)  (although for now i will muddle on following standard practices - i am a bit wary of making languages be what they are not...)

Answer (score 2):

A proof of concept using `lapply`

A dummy version of read norm

```
readnorm <- function(n){
 a <- data.frame(raw = 1:10)
 a <- list(n=n, raw = a$raw, normed = runif(10))
}
```

use `lapply`

```
.list <- lapply(1:5, readnorm)
```

set the names (manually)

```
names(.list) <- 1:5
```

A function to get the data from this list

```
get_data <- function(.list, .which){
 .x <- data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(.list, '[[', .which)))
 names(.x) <- names(.list)
 return(.x)
}
```

get all the data in `a` named as raw

```
raw <- get_data(.list, 'raw')
raw$'1'
```

or the same for `normed`

```
normed <- get_data(.list, 'normed')

normed$'1'
```